# Route in Subroute with Middleware in NodeJs Express

Tags: node.js, express, routes, middleware

I don't to put all by main routes in my server.js file, so the main file of my express server, because they are too many. Now I created a subroute named auth where the login, register, emailverification and passwordreset are in.

I created two functions to check if the user is logged in or not and now I need to check that the user is not logged in when registering or logging in, but the emailverification he needs to. Therefor, I can't set it as a middle ware in the app.use() function.

server.js:

```
const userRoute = require("./routes/user");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");

const app = express();

(async () => await connection())();

app.use("/auth", authRoute);

async function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  const auth = await checkJWT(req.cookies.token);

  if (auth === 500) return res.status(500).send();

  if (!auth) return res.status(401).send();

  req.user = auth;
  return next();
}

async function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  const auth = await checkJWT(req.cookies.token);

  if (auth === 500) return res.status(500).send();

  if (auth) return res.status(401).send();

  return next();
}

async function checkJWT(token) {
  try {
    ...
    return user;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return 500;
  }
}

app.use("/user", checkAuthenticated, userRoute);

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("backend running on Port: 3001");
});
```

Now I import the checkNotAuth function to the /auth route file and add it to the routes...

```
const express = require("express");

const { checkAuthenticated, checkNotAuthenticated } = require("../server");

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/login", checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  ...
  return res.status(401).send();
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now I get this error:
**Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]**

when I remove the checkNotAuth middleware, there is no error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is likely because you aren't doing the export and import properly.  If you do `console.log(checkNotAuthenticated)` in the module where you're trying to use it, it probably will say it's an object or undefined, not the desired function.  You don't show the export code for that function - I'm guessing that's where the issue is.

Comment: FYI, this wrapper around this does nothing useful `(async () => await connection())();`  That works exactly the same as just `connection()`.  This is because the `await` just causes the `async` function to immediately return a promise which you do nothing with.  So, it's identical to `connection()` returning a promise that you do nothing with.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks. Yes, you are correct, it is undefined. But how can I export it then? I just tried module.exports = {checkAuth} but this is also not working.

2.) Oh yes. Thanks :D

Comment: Ok, I think I found a solution. I just put the two functions into a separate file and from there I can export them without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I can't export these two functions from the server.js file for some reason, I just put them in there on file and exported them there. Now I import them in the server and auth route file.